# Long attributes in the meta tag

Tags: html, seo, search-engine

I have a meta tag for description:

```
<meta name="description"
      content="a very very long string that is rather boring" />
```

Is it OK to put the content on multiple lines so that it is readable for editing? Is this true for all browsers and search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it OK to put the content on multiple lines so that it is readable for editing?

Yes.

> Is this true for all browsers and search engines?

Yes.

So long as the content is valid attribute content, you will be fine with this.

HTML 4 defines the [content attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-content) as [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata):

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities. User agents should interpret attribute values as follows:
>
> - Replace character entities with characters,
> - Ignore line feeds,
> - Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space.

Answer (score 2):

By the specifications, a line break in the attribute value is equivalent to a space, as described in Oded’s answer.

However, there is really no guarantee that programs actually follow the rules here. They fail to do that for some other attributes (with CDATA value), such as in the display of a `title` attribute as a tooltip. And in fact, if you right click on a page in Firefox and select Page Info, you will see the `content` attribute value so that line breaks are preserved, instead of being replaced by spaces.

On the other hand, the attribute is mainly intended for search engines. Nobody can really say whether *all* search engines behave the same way in this respect. But commonly used search engines seem to treat `content` attribute values in this case in a manner where the difference between a space and a line break does not matter.